# Jest Mocking Issue: 'mockImplementation' Does Not Exist

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I am working on a TypeScript project that uses DataLoader for batch fetching. I have a function named getLoaders that returns an object with DataLoader instances for different entity types.

```js
import DataLoader from 'dataloader';
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';
import { Address, batchEntitiesBy } from './somewhere';

export type LoadersType = ReturnType<typeof getLoaders>;

export function getLoaders(em: EntityManager) {
  return {
    addressById: new DataLoader<number, Address>((ids) =>
      batchEntitiesBy<Address, 'id'>(em, Address, 'id', ids)
    ),
    // Some other similar dataloaders
  };
}
```

In another file, I have a function called processAddress that takes one of these loaders objects as an argument.

```js
export function processAddress(id: number, loaders: LoadersType): string {
  const Address = loaders.addressById.load(id);
  // Do something with Address
  return Address.name;
}
```

I would like to write Jest tests for processAddress where I can mock different implementations of the load function for different test cases.

Here's my attempt to do so:

```js
  jest.mock('dataloader', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        load: jest.fn(),
        loadMany: jest.fn(),
        // ... any other methods you want to mock
      };
    });
  });

describe('processAddress', () => {
  const loadersMock = getLoaders({} as EntityManager);

  it('should call load with first mock', async () => {
    loadersMock.addressById.load.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ name: 'mocked value 1' }));
    
    const result = await processAddress(1, loadersMock);
    
    expect(loadersMock.addressById.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(loadersMock.addressById.load).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    expect(result).toBe('mocked value 1');
  });

  it('should call load with second mock', async () => {
    loadersMock.addressById.load.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ name: 'mocked value 2' }));
    
    const result = await processAddress(2, loadersMock);
    
    expect(loadersMock.addressById.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(loadersMock.addressById.load).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
    expect(result).toBe('mocked value 2');
  });
});
```

On the line

```
loadersMock.addressById.load.mockImplementation(() => ...
```

I am getting the error:

```
Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type
```

When I change it to

```
(loadersMock.addressById.load as jest.Mock)).mockImplementation(() => ...
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: loadersMock.addressById.load.mockImplementation is not a function
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, `loadersMock.addressById.load.mockImplementation` works fine for me